# I need to convert my hourly data to daily data by taking the sum

Tags: r, aggregate

data set :

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(1506406740, 1506406770, 1506406860, 
1506406890, 1506406920, 1506406950, 1506406980, 1506407010, 1506407040, 
1506407070), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
Column3 = c(131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 
131), m_Pm = c(2.402842, 2.556558, 2.805165, 2.97428, 3.101824, 
3.23984, 3.359587, 3.474448, 3.62753, 3.773597)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It works alright till the first aggregate function . after that I am not able to get the correct answer after the sum function . I'm getting large values instead

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

attach(data)
data %>% #filtering 131 and 132
  select(time,Column3,m_Pm) %>%
  filter(data,Column3=="131") 
filter(data,Column3=="132")
data_131<-filter(data,Column3=="131") 
data_132<-filter(data,Column3=="132") 

#datehour column (dailyaverage)
data_131$datehour<-format(data_131$time,"%Y-%m-%d %H")
aggregate(m_Pm~datehour,data_131, mean)

#datecolumn

data_131$date1<-format(data_131$time,"%Y-%m-%d")
dE_131<-aggregate(m_Pm~date1,data_131,sum)
dE_131}
```

Since the data is too huge, I cannot post it here. 
It is a 7 months data of every 30 seconds.

Comment: please share your dataset as well.

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara check edit

Comment: image is not good. you can run `dput(head(YourDataSet,10))`, and it gives you a sample of 10 rows

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara done

Comment: Take a look at `tibbletime` package https://github.com/business-science/tibbletime

Comment: `aggregate(.~time,transform(data,time=as.Date(time)),sum)`

Comment: @Onyambu sorry I dint get it

Comment: @fatma try again

Comment: @Onyambu where should I add this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(dayH= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d %H"), day= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
       group_by(dayH) %>% mutate(th=mean(m_Pm)) %>% distinct(dayH, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
       group_by(day) %>% summarise(tday=sum(th))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  day         tday
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 2017-09-26  15.7


df %>% mutate(dayH= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d %H"), day= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d"), month=format(time,"%Y-%m")) %>% 
       group_by(dayH) %>% mutate(th=mean(m_Pm)) %>% distinct(dayH, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
       group_by(day) %>% mutate(tday=sum(th)) %>% distinct(day, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
       group_by(month) %>% summarise(tmonth=sum(tday))
```

Comment: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: invalid 'trim' argument.

Comment: but i need to sum the hourly data to get total daily value

Comment: hello , first i take hourly value by taking mean on hourly basis . now i want to take sum of the hourly data to get daily . i hope you got it

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @A.Suliman thank you so much ! and after this what if I want to add up all daily data into one to get monthly value ? please help

Comment: i need help again