# How to assign mutate and distinct to another variable in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kdv2.png)I have a huge data set which has data for every 30 seconds . First I get the mean to take hourly data , then sum it for daily data and again sum it for monthly data . I need to assign the mutate function to a new data set / variable called mE_131 . for plotting monthly value  .I'm new to this Please Help!

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

attach(data)
data%>% #filtering 131 and 132
  select(time,Column3,m_Pm) %>%
  filter(data,Column3=="131") 
filter(data,Column3=="132")
data_131<-filter(data,Column3=="131") 
data_132<-filter(data,Column3=="132") 

data_131%>%
  mutate(datehour= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d %H"), date1= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d"), month=format(time,"%Y-%m")) %>% 
  group_by(datehour) %>% mutate(hourlyP=mean(m_Pm)) %>% distinct(datehour, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(date1) %>% mutate(dailyP=sum(hourlyP)) %>% distinct(date1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% summarise(monthlyP=sum(dailyP))
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of what `data` looks like and what kind of output you'd like to get?

Comment: this is my data . check the link .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252916/i-need-to-convert-my-hourly-data-to-daily-data-by-taking-the-sum/52253724?noredirect=1#comment91464408_52253724

Comment: @JonSpring I just want to assign my mutate to another data set called mE_131 to plot it and then compare with another data set . thanks

Comment: @JonSpring pls help

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you're hoping to do. Is there a way you can show an example of what you want?

Comment: seems you are on the right track, just you need to add ` %>% ggplot(aes(month, monthlyP)) + geom_point()` to your last line.

Comment: @SandipanDey but I want to make a new data set called mE_131 which stores the new values such as month , monthlyP etc

Comment: @JonSpring I want to transfer my new columns such as monthlyP , month etc to a new data set called mE_131 . I have the same kind of data for 132 as well . so i need to compare 131 and 132 monthly values to draw a bar graph

Comment: @JonSpring check the image I added

Comment: @SandipanDey thanks but I want my whole mutate function to be stored in another new variable . please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to compare monthly data between `column3 == 131` and `column3 == 132` then you don't necessarily need to create a separate dataset for each of them although I will show you how to do it in the end.

First, let's create the required summary for both `131` and `132` :

```
data <- data %>%
    filter(column3 == "131" | column3 == "132") %>% # filtering the required data only
    mutate(datehour= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d %H"), # calculate the required stats
          date1= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d"),
          month=format(time,"%Y-%m")) %>% 
   group_by(datehour) %>%
   mutate(hourlyP=mean(m_Pm)) %>%
   distinct(datehour, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(date1) %>%
   mutate(dailyP=sum(hourlyP)) %>%
   distinct(date1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(month) %>% 
   summarise(monthlyP=sum(dailyP))
```

Note: I have written every part of code in separate line to enhance readability but it is basically the same as your code shown above.

Now, let's do the plotting:

```
data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=month, y=monthlyP, fill=column3)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge") # this will produce similar plot as in your example
```

If you insist on having a separate dataset for each value in `column3` then you can simply use the assignment operator `<-` to create a new dataframe as follows

```
mE_131 <- data_131 %>%
   mutate(datehour= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d %H"), 
          date1= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d"),
          month=format(time,"%Y-%m")) %>% 
   group_by(datehour) %>%
   mutate(hourlyP=mean(m_Pm)) %>%
   distinct(datehour, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(date1) %>%
   mutate(dailyP=sum(hourlyP)) %>%
   distinct(date1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(month) %>% 
   summarise(monthlyP=sum(dailyP))
```

Then do the same thing to create `mE_132`. However, I don't recommend this because it would be harder to plot them.

Comment: So do I do , mE_131<-transmute (data_131, mutate(datehour= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d %H"), date1= format(time,"%Y-%m-%d"), month=format(time,"%Y-%m")) %>% 
  group_by(datehour) %>% mutate(hourlyP=mean(m_Pm)) %>% distinct(datehour, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(date1) %>% mutate(dailyP=sum(hourlyP)) %>% distinct(date1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% summarise(monthlyP=sum(dailyP)))  ??????

Comment: my function is the big mutate function .

Comment: please help . I'm new to this

Comment: Please see the edit, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: kinda same data set . but error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277425/cannot-perform-mutate-due-to-posixit-error     please help me...

Comment: @fatma see the answer on the post. Glad to help