# Cannot perform mutate due to POSIXIt error

Tags: r

I have data which has time in the format of m/d/Y H/m/s . I am not able to perform mutate function due to PosixIt error . please help .

My data :

```
structure(list(time = "9/26/2017 6:19:00", panel = 230, mpp = 2.68627), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My code :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data2%>% #filtering 230 and 231
  select(time,panel,mpp)%>%
  filter(data2,panel=="230")
filter(data2,panel=="231")
data_230<-filter(data2,panel=="230")
data_231<-filter(data2,panel=="231")
data_230
data_231

install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)
#data_230$ts <- strptime(data_230$time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

#data_230$tsf <- ymd_hms(data_230$ts)

library(dplyr)


  #data_230%>%
  data_230$ts <- as.POSIXct(strptime(data_230$time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    data_230$tsf <- ymd_hms(data_230$ts)

    data_230 %>% mutate(ts=strptime(time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),tsf=ymd_hms(ts)) %>% mutate(datehour= format(time,"%m-%d-%Y %H"), date1= format(time,"%m-%d-%Y"), month=format(time,"%m-%Y")) %>% 
    group_by(datehour) %>% mutate(hourlyP=mean(mpp)) %>% distinct(datehour, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(date1) %>% mutate(dailyP=sum(hourlyP)) %>% distinct(date1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(month) %>% summarise(monthlyP=sum(dailyP))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @doviod  Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column 'ts` is of unsupported class POSIXlt

Comment: @doviod please help . I'm a newbie

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` functions can best handle datetime data as `POSIXct` objects. So I recommend that you modify the code as the following:

```
data_230 <- filter(data2, panel=="230")

data_230$time <-  as.POSIXct(strptime(
                                      data_230$time,
                                      "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
                             ) # convert your character column to POSIXct object
# then the rest of your code:
data_230 %>% 
    mutate(ts = as.POSIXct(strptime(time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
           tsf = ymd_hms(ts))) %>%
    mutate(datehour = format(time,"%m-%d-%Y %H"),
           date1 = format(time,"%m-%d-%Y"),
           month = format(time,"%m-%Y")) %>% 
    group_by(datehour) %>% 
    mutate(hourlyP=mean(mpp)) %>%
    distinct(datehour, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(date1) %>% 
    mutate(dailyP=sum(hourlyP)) %>% 
    distinct(date1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(month) %>% 
    summarise(monthlyP=sum(dailyP))
```

Although I don't really get why you need `ts` and `tsf`, the code runs and produces the following ouput:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  month   monthlyP
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 09-2017     2.69
```